# How to setup Alpine Linux in headless mode over ethernet with SSH?

Tags: linux, networking, installation, headless, alpine-linux

I want to set up Alpine Linux on a Raspberry Pi over SSH, but I have no monitor and keyboard at hand.
I copy the tarball to the formatted SD card as described in the Alpine Linux wiki, add an executable `/bin/hostname` script, plug it into the Pi and attach it to my router over ethernet and give it power.

I read this article: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_-_Headless_Installation,
and 'forked' the setup script like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    
    cat <<EOF >> /etc/network/interfaces
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
    
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    
    EOF
    
    service networking start
    rm /var/run/ifstate
    
    /sbin/setup-ssd -c openssh
    cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.orig
    
    cat <<EOF >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    PermitEmptyPasswords yes
    PermitRootLogin yes
    EOF
    
    service sshd restart
    mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config.orig /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    
    rm /bin/hostname
    ln -s /bin/busybox /bin/hostname
```

But it does not work. When I power up the Pi, only the Power LED is lighting up, nothing else is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check https://github.com/macmpi/alpine-linux-headless-bootstrap for a more current solution.
Works on Alpine 3.16, and can even setup PiZero & Pi4 through simple USB ethernet-gadget networking.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1134215)

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for some time, eventually tried with the combination of architectures and releases listed on the wiki page (aarch64 & alpine 3.11.2) and it worked straight away on my RPI3B